# Is it legal for me to use publicly accessible user data about a person on my website?

Tags: gdpr, data-ownership

I run a wiki service and I was wondering if someone doxes an anonymous person in the from of a dump (pastebin, screenshots, recordings etc), can we keep that data or perhaps cite it?

For instance if someone writes an article about a famous person (or soon to be) and also proceeds to dox them in it (home address, name, and so on). Then can we use or save that data on our wiki under GDPR?

Comment: Please define "dox."

Comment: @phoog Consider the hypothesis that someone is using a pseudonym on a service online, is famous under that psuedonym and does not wish to have his/her information publicised. Then one day someone publishes their information on a pastebin or website somewhere without consent. This would be a form of doxing.

Comment: See "Canary Mission". They have been controversial for republishing data that people post to their public social media profiles. Sounds similar to what you're asking

Answer (score 1):

In the absence of more information I think this is a question only you can answer about your service. While reading the GDPR you must consider how your service operates.

https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/HTML/?uri=CELEX:02016R0679-20160504&from=EN

Does your service operate according to the six Principles relating to processing of personal data under Article 5?

Does your service abide by at least one of the six clauses under Article 6, Lawfulness of processing? (In the context I imagine the only possible clause is (f), that you're pursuing a "legitimate interest", if so you need to be clear about what that is.)

Does your service process the "special categories of data" under Article 9(1) and if so on what basis under 9(2)? Does your service process personal data relating to criminal convictions and offences, Article 10?

Does your service uphold the Rights of the data subject under Chapter III? Article 14 will be of particular interest.